# What are creative uses for retired arrows?

Tags: gear, archery

[This question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/6034/what-are-creative-uses-for-retired-carabiners) about retired carbines made me think about my retired arrows. I've a lot of them which can't be shot anymore. Either they've a slight crack anywhere or they're just completely broken.

[image]

[image]

What are some creative uses for retired arrows?

Comment: This is a little uncreative, but i would just put them on display. Maybe some of them tell stories of mishaps and unlikely hits. You could also recycle parts of them. But these ideas don't answer your question, thus my input will stay a comment :) Just make sure no one still tries to shoot one of the less damaged broken arrows.

Comment: Uhmm, spray them so you can recognize a mile away otherwise youll end picking one up, Murphy is always waiting... If damaged at the ends they can be cut, sleeved and reused sometimes. Bow arrows can be shortened as bolts for crossbows. Depends on materials. But usually they are for the "RobinHood thing" Halloween stuff, demos, part of target stands... use them for plants, bird perches... make pens out of them...

Comment: @ErikvanDoren Why not turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: I'll create a community wiki answer and you will be able to edit your comments into it :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

Comment: @ErikvanDoren Great ideas Erik! You might want to add them to the list ⬇

Comment: @Peter1807 These are good ideas! Make sure to add them to the list beneath ⬇

Comment: @Roflo, didnt think it was developed enough to be a proper answer.

Comment: @ OddDeer, I added them below together with a few more, not sure if the the formatting is ok, have difficulties with it on the cellphone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm creating this [answer as a community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)<sub>1</sub>, since everyone comes to the question and posts a single idea beneath it as a comment :) Instead of doing so, we might want to add the ideas to this list:

1. Create an arrow-shaft-pen
2. If damaged at the ends they can be cut, sleeved and reused sometimes. Bow arrows can be shortened as bolts for crossbows.       Depends on materials.
3. The "RobinHood thing"
4. Halloween stuff
5. demos (either if a club has an open day and the arrows have been rebuilt but they dont fly that well, or to show people how arrows are    with cutouts and description tags, or when teaching how to build arrows)
6. part of target stands...
7. use them for plants, bird perches...
8. some aluminum ones can make sleeves to repair tent poles or stakes
9. minimal backpack frame
10. parts of rc models
11. couch blowgun dart shooting
12. I found that 22 shells fit nicely in my old crossbow bolts, i cut them off just long enough for 15 rounds. makes reloading my 22 real fast and easy.
13. Old arrows also make great pepper plant stakes for the garden.
14. Cut off the tip and hot-glue a large treble hook in it...makes a great ice fishing gaff
15. Couple guys at work put them on their antenna of their truck, with some tape or heat shrink at the bottom to hold it on
16. Weld or solder them into large abstract sculptures.  You may even be able to sell the sculptures.
17. Make a kite - putt a nock on each end of two arrows, making a cross, tie the junction, run string around the outside of the frame to make the kite edges.  Use a plastic sack or garbage bag as the face of the kite and an iron to melt the edges over the string around the end.  Add string and tail.  I loved these when my dad made them for me as a kid.

---

<sub>1)</sub>

> Community wiki posts work by partly transferring ownership of the post
>   from the original author to the community. They make the post easier
>   to edit and maintain by a wider group of users, but they do not
>   contribute to any user's reputation.